# Convert strings of list to list of integers inside a list

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have a list of strings and those strings are lists. Like this: `['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']`, for example. I want to get a list of lists or even every list there:

```
[[1,2,3],[10,12,5]]
```

Comment: So what went wrong when you tried?

Comment: It's hard to explain.... I want just an element, but I could not get to him with a str instead of a list. so, when I ran my program, it was splitting everything, even brackets. But I already got help, so I think I can handle it now, thanks.

Comment: where is this data coming from?

Comment: the data is coming from a file

Answer (score 2):

You should use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get actual `list` object from `string`.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> data =  ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']
>>> data = [literal_eval(each) for each in data]
>>> data
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 12, 5]]
```

`literal_eval` safely evaluates each object.

```
>>> help(literal_eval)
Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

literal_eval(node_or_string)
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
```

You should always try to avoid using `eval` function. Read more [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`, `eval` should generally be avoided:

```
l= ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']

from ast import literal_eval

print([literal_eval(ele) for ele in l])
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 12, 5]]
```

Or index, split and map:

```
print([list(map(int,ele[1:-1].split(","))) for ele in l])
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 12, 5]]
```

If you always have the same format splitting is the most efficient solution:

```
In [44]: %%timeit                       
l= ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']
l = [choice(l) for _ in range(1000)]
[eval(ele) for ele in l]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.15 ms per loop

In [45]: %%timeit
l= ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']
l = [choice(l) for _ in range(1000)]
[literal_eval(ele) for ele in l]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop

In [46]: %%timeit                       
l= ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']
l = [choice(l) for _ in range(1000)]
[list(map(int,ele[1:-1].split(","))) for ele in l]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.07 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)

```
import ast
l =  ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']
l = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often not recommended, but you could use `eval` for each string:

```
fun = ['[1,2,3]','[10,12,5]']
listy = [eval(x) for x in fun]
```

**Outputs:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 12, 5]]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) provides excellent reason as to why using `eval` can be a bad idea. I am just presenting it here as an option. `eval` can pose a large security risk, as you are giving user input the full power of the Python interpreter. Additionally, it violates one of the fundamental principles of programming, which states that ***all*** of your executable code should directly map to your source code. Evaluating user input with `eval` leads to executable code that evidently isn't in your source.

Using `ast.literal_eval()` is preferable, and [Padraic Cunningham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29610309/4686625) addresses how to use it effectively.

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expressions:

```
new_list = [[int(j) for j in re.findall(r'\d+', i)] for i in old_list]
```

Comment: Do you understand it? Basically it searches each string for a number and it  casts all of these number strings into integers.

Comment: where do you get that re.findall?

Comment: @DianaVasconcelosFerreira You have to  `import re`